# route to specified number of views in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router

I am in the process of building a mobile web app with AngularJS. The app will allow the user to record the salary and other figures for employees.

On the first page the user will select the number of employees to be filled for instance 3. When the user clicks next, it will go to employee 1 then next to employee 2 and so on.

The problem is i am having these views do not exist. I will create an augular directive which will contain the elements to be captured for the employee. But then how to route to these views. It should allow to go back as well to edit for any employee.

Any advise is welcome.
Thanks,
Ashley

Answer (score 0):

You can have one state with the form and another parameterised state with the employee ID.

```
$stateProvider .state('contacts.detail', 
{ 
    url: "/contacts/:contactId", 
    templateUrl: 'contacts.detail.html',
    controller: function ($stateParams) { 
       // If we got here from a url of /contacts/42
       expect($stateParams).toBe({contactId: "42"});
    }
})
```

From one employee editing state you can navigate to the next employee editing state.

More info/examples: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing